# two way paypal transcation between paypal accounts

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can I implement two way paypal transaction between two account using C#, It's not buyer and sender. i have tried payment using paypal it need secret and client id. I want this to be between two paypal accounts.Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: To integrate `Paypal` in a Asp.net MVC app, [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/870870/Using-Paypal-Rest-API-with-ASP-NET-MVC) can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You want your application to send money between two accounts? You could take a look at PayPal's API if you're qualified for it (must be a verified business account I think) but if there's no way of getting accepted for mass payments then you'll have to do some cheeky bot moves, which isn't legit at all, so might not help you.